# Handling exceptions in spring boot due to foreign key violation

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, exception

I am using hibernate in my spring boot rest application
In one of the put API calls, there is a possibility of an exception due to a foreign
key violation. The line that will cause the issue is: `transaction.commit()`
Currently, when this exception happens, the postman response shows:

> {
> "timestamp": "2022-06-07T10:26:29.473+00:00",
> "status": 500,
> "error": "Internal Server Error",
> "path": "/addSt" }
> Is there a way to handle it gracefully?  The current method signature looks like:

```
@PutMapping("/addSt")  
    public void addSt(@RequestParam("cd") String cd)
```

One approach is to put transaction.commit() in a try-catch block and return some meaningful  message.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken,

If you just use hibernate the exception throw should be **MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException**,.

if you use JPA and Hibernate then it should be a **DataIntegrityViolationException**.

In spring boot rest, to gracefully handle exception, the best is to use a **ControllerAdvice**, in this class you can handle all the exception throws by your application.

I advise you to read this article about it, it will help you :
https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring#controlleradvice